# Unshare all files, folders and subfolders on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like my script to be able to unshare all folders, subfolders and files in my Google Drive. So far it only unshares specific files by using the folder id. Help is much appreciated

```html
function RemoveEditors(){
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1uus-Cv3n1xxQbSyWakQwqp7vNtTJGnWe").getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next()
  var docs = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
  var users = docs.getEditors();
      for (i in users) {
        email = users[i].getEmail();
     if (email != "") {
      docs.removeEditor(email);

}
}
}
```

Comment: You can post code in your question.  That would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function RemoveEditors(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next()
    var docs = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
    var users = docs.getEditors();
    for (i in users) {
      email = users[i].getEmail();
      if (email != "") {
        docs.removeEditor(email);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles()) will allow you to get all of the files in the drive, then you can do the same process you had before.

**EDIT**

After reviewing the question I noticed you wanted to remove all perimssions, edit and view included, so I'm updating the code to go over all files & folders and remove both view and edit permissions, I'm leaving the old code as a reference. The new code:

```
function removePermissions(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next()
    var docs = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

    var editors = docs.getEditors();
    var viewers = docs.getViewers();
    var email;

    for (i in editors) {
      email = editors[i].getEmail();
      if (email != "") {
        docs.removeEditor(email);
      }
    }
    for (i in viewers) {
      email = viewers[i].getEmail();
      if (email != "") {
        docs.removeViewer(email);
      }
    }
  }
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next()
    var docs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId());

    var editors = docs.getEditors();
    var viewers = docs.getViewers();
    var email;

    for (i in editors) {
      email = editors[i].getEmail();
      if (email != "") {
        docs.removeEditor(email);
      }
    }
    for (i in viewers) {
      email = viewers[i].getEmail();
      if (email != "") {
        docs.removeViewer(email);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alberto. It works perfect! One last question, what should I do to remove editors from folders? The script removes all editors from each and every file in my google drive and I would like to do the same with existing folders. Appreciate the help

Comment: It would be the same process, but using `getFolders()` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolders)) and `removeEditor()` from the folder instead of the file ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removeeditoremailaddress))

Comment: @KarenSmith forgot to specify, using `getFolders()` instead of `getFiles()`, just want to be perfectly clear

Comment: Works great. Thank you so much